# Homeomorphism between a compact space and non compact space

Tags: general-topology

Is it possible to have a homeomorphism between a compact space and a non compact space?

If both of them are Hausdorff, it's trivial because the image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact. But what if they are not both Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Compactness is a topological property (like Hausdorffness, connectedness, separability,...), hence preserved by homeomorphisms. It is quite easy to prove. Did you try methodically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. A homeomorphism is an open continuous bijection. So if you have an open cover of one space, you can make it into an open cover of the other space. And if one of them has a finite subcover, so has the other...